# Creating an auto-scroll in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I am creating an application in Xamarin.I want to use Auto-Scroll feature and i am not able to do that in a proper way. I am able to scroll manually. BUt i want to display the next picture automatically without scrolling.
Kindly share your views and codes.

I have used sliders for now. But i would like to know if i can do something better.

```
        Grid SliderGrid = new Grid ();
        //SliderGrid.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
        //SliderGrid.Padding = 10;
        int SlidercolumnCount = Slider.Count;
        RowDefinition Sliderrow = new RowDefinition ();         
        SliderGrid.RowDefinitions.Add (Sliderrow);
        for (int j = 0; j < SlidercolumnCount; j++) {
            ColumnDefinition col = new ColumnDefinition ();
            SliderGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add (col);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < SlidercolumnCount; i++) {
            var vetImageCol = new Image {
                HeightRequest=260,
                WidthRequest=360,
                BindingContext = Slider [i],
                Source = Slider [i].CategoryImage,
                Aspect=Aspect.AspectFill,
            };
            Grid.SetColumn (vetImageCol, i);        
            SliderGrid.Children.Add (vetImageCol);
        }
        var SliderContent = new ScrollView {
            Orientation=ScrollOrientation.Horizontal,
            HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            //HeightRequest=265,
            Content= SliderGrid,
        };
```

Comment: is this for android? ios? how you display your images with viewpager? in an imageview and you just change your image? show us your code, we cant help you with so general question

Comment: it is for android. is it okay if we include timer kinda thing??!!

Answer (score 1):

It's ok to do it with Task commands like this one:

```
private async void DoSomethingAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    DoSomething();
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    DoSomethingelse();
}
```

Although it's better to do it with Task return value instead of void but you get the idea

Comment: will try that. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //page view is may ui scroll view 
    //counter for if my image focus on last image then return on 1 img 
    //new PointF((float)(your image size * count),your top margin or your fram y);

    int count = 0;
                public async void StartTimer()
                {
                    await Task.Delay(3000); //3 sec 

                    count += 1;
                    if (count == 5)
                    {
                        count = 0;
                    }
                    var bottomOffset = new PointF((float)(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width * count),0);
                    pageview.SetContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true);
                    StartTimer();          


                }


public override void ViewDidLoad(){
 StartTimer();  
}
```

Comment: Please describe how your solution works and the thought process involved in coming to this conclusion instead of just posting code.